# Android: Fragment to Fragment Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

When I go from Fragment A to B, Fragment B's `onResume()` is called first and then Fragment A's `onPause()` is called. Which is different from Activity lifecycle.

How to solve this?

Comment: why would you want to change this? what is the problem?

Comment: @MikhailKim Usually in Activity when we go from A to B, first A's onPause() is called and then B's onResume() is called.

Comment: Why do you rely on that ordering? It's an optimization from framework.

Answer (score 0):

Check out - https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/fragment-lifecycle-during-fragment-transaction/ ..
It explains fragment lifecycle during fragment transaction with latest appcompat version.

As per latest appcomat version, if setAllowOptimization() is set to true then during replacing fragments `onResume()` is called before `onPause()` otherwise `onPause()` is called before `onResume()`.
setAllowOptimization() is used to set whether or not to allow optimization operation within and across transactions.

Comment: Link only answers are not advised as the URL could die, if you could edit your answer to add some of the vital information relevant to the scope of the question that is in the URL, that would benefit future readers.

Comment: I didn't setAllowOptimization(), How do I disable this?

Comment: @WideFide By default setAllowOptimization is set to false..u don't need to disable it separately by code..make sure u r using latest appcompat version